# Upload Directory with files to S3 using Java

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-s3, jets3t

I'm working on the application where user will upload ZIP file to my server, on the server that ZIP file will be expanded and then I need to upload it to the server. Now my questions is: how to upload directory with multiple files and sub-folders using Java to S3 bucket? Is there any examples for that? Currently i'm using JetS3t to manage all my communications with S3.

Comment: http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html#uploading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built something very similar. After expanding the zip on the server call FileUtils.listFiles() which will recursively list files in a folder. Just iterate the list and create s3objects and upload the files to s3. Make use of the threadedstorage service so that multiple files can be uploaded at the same time. Also ensure you process the upload events. If some files couldn't be uploaded the jets3t library will tell you. 
I could post the code I wrote once get into the office.

**EDIT: CODE:**

Here's the code:

```
    private static ProviderCredentials credentials;
private static S3Service s3service;
private static ThreadedS3Service storageService;
private static S3Bucket bucket;
private List<S3Object> s3Objs=new ArrayList<S3Object>();
private Set<String> s3ObjsCompleted=new HashSet<String>();
private boolean isErrorOccured=true;
private final ByteFormatter byteFormatter = new ByteFormatter();
private final TimeFormatter timeFormatter = new TimeFormatter();


    private void initialise() throws ServiceException, S3ServiceException {
    credentials=<create your credentials>;
        s3service = new RestS3Service(credentials);
        bucket = new S3Bucket(<bucket details>);
        storageService=new ThreadedS3Service(s3service, this);
    }
}

private void uploadFolder(File folder) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    readFolderContents(folder);
    uploadFilesInList(folder);
}
private void readFolderContents(File folder) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    Iterator<File> filesinFolder=FileUtils.iterateFiles(folder,null,null);

    while(filesinFolder.hasNext()) {
        File file=filesinFolder.next();
        String key = <create your key from the filename or something>;
        S3Object s3Obj=new S3Object(bucket, file);
        s3Obj.setKey(key);
        s3Obj.setContentType(Mimetypes.getInstance().getMimetype(s3Obj.getKey()));
        s3Objs.add(s3Obj);  
    }
}
private void uploadFilesInList(File folder) {
    logger.debug("Uploading files in folder "+folder.getAbsolutePath());
    isErrorOccured=false;
    s3ObjsCompleted.clear();

    storageService.putObjects(bucket.getName(), s3Objs.toArray(new S3Object[s3Objs.size()]));   

    if(isErrorOccured || s3Objs.size()!=s3ObjsCompleted.size()) {
        logger.debug("Have to try uploading a few objects again for folder "+folder.getAbsolutePath()+" - Completed = "+s3ObjsCompleted.size()+" and Total ="+s3Objs.size());
        List<S3Object> s3ObjsRemaining=new ArrayList<S3Object>();
        for(S3Object s3Obj : s3Objs) {
            if(!s3ObjsCompleted.contains(s3Obj.getKey())) {
                s3ObjsRemaining.add(s3Obj);
            }
        }
        s3Objs=s3ObjsRemaining;
        uploadFilesInList(folder);
    }
}

@Override
public void event(CreateObjectsEvent event) {
    super.event(event);
    if (ServiceEvent.EVENT_IGNORED_ERRORS == event.getEventCode()) {
        Throwable[] throwables = event.getIgnoredErrors();
        for (int i = 0; i < throwables.length; i++) {
            logger.error("Ignoring error: " + throwables[i].getMessage());
        }
    }else if(ServiceEvent.EVENT_STARTED == event.getEventCode()) {
        logger.debug("**********************************Upload Event Started***********************************");
    }else if(event.getEventCode()==ServiceEvent.EVENT_ERROR) {
        isErrorOccured=true;
    }else if(event.getEventCode()==ServiceEvent.EVENT_IN_PROGRESS) {
        StorageObject[] storeObjs=event.getCreatedObjects();
        for(StorageObject storeObj : storeObjs) {
            s3ObjsCompleted.add(storeObj.getKey());
        }
        ThreadWatcher watcher = event.getThreadWatcher();
        if (watcher.getBytesTransferred() >= watcher.getBytesTotal()) {
            logger.debug("Upload Completed.. Verifying");
        }else {
            int percentage = (int) (((double) watcher.getBytesTransferred() / watcher.getBytesTotal()) * 100);

            long bytesPerSecond = watcher.getBytesPerSecond();
            StringBuilder transferDetailsText=new StringBuilder("Uploading.... ");
            transferDetailsText.append("Speed: " + byteFormatter.formatByteSize(bytesPerSecond) + "/s");

            if (watcher.isTimeRemainingAvailable()) {
                long secondsRemaining = watcher.getTimeRemaining();
                if (transferDetailsText.length() > 0) {
                    transferDetailsText.append(" - ");
                }
                transferDetailsText.append("Time remaining: " + timeFormatter.formatTime(secondsRemaining));
            }

            logger.debug(transferDetailsText.toString()+" "+percentage);
        }
    }else if(ServiceEvent.EVENT_COMPLETED==event.getEventCode()) {
        logger.debug("**********************************Upload Event Completed***********************************");
        if(isErrorOccured) {
            logger.debug("**********************But with errors, have to retry failed uploads**************************");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sethu. It works! the one thing that is not working is the creation of the sub-directories. What it does it makes everything flat. Do you have any idea why that's is happening? Is your code creating sub-directories in your S3?

One more thing. In your code I had to modify FileUtils.iterateFiles(folder,null,null); to FileUtils.iterateFiles(folder,null,true);

Comment: Oh, never mind. I just figured that the file key will have the directory (ex. images/image.jpg). Here is what I did in my code: file.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll(filePath+"/", "");

Answer (score 26):

HI This is the simple way to upload the Directory into S3 bucket.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key_id,
            secret_access_key);
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);

    TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();

    MultipleFileUpload upload = tm.uploadDirectory(existingBucketName,
            "BuildNumber#1", "FilePathYouWant", true);
```

Comment: **Video Stream** `FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(vedio_filepath);
 ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
 PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
 s3_BucketName, location_KEY, stream,objectMetadata);`

Comment: To create an instance of TransferManager better to use TransferManagerBuilder.defaultTransferManager() as the constructor of TransferManager is deprecated

Comment: If you want to related to a S3Client object you could use **TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();**

Comment: This approach isn't supported in SDK 2.x https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577177/alternative-for-transfermanager-in-aws-sdk-java-2-x

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in December of 2021 since BasicAWSCredentials is deprecated now.

```
        AWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(env.getProperty("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                env.getProperty("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"));
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(AWSCredentials))
                .build();

        TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();

MultipleFileUpload upload = tm.uploadDirectory(existingBucketName,
            "BuildNumber#1", "FilePathYouWant", true);
```